# FCM api not detecting invalid token

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

When using FCM rest API to send a message to an app that has been removed from a device, the FCM api is returning a status code of 200 instead of a 400 or 404 as expected.  The app has been uninstalled for about a week and many push attempts have been made with all tests returning a code of 200

So I am wondering :

- is there an expected time period before FCM knows that an app has been uninstalled and therefore the token is invalid ?
- is there something that the app has to do when acquiring the token for FCM to properly mark the token as invalid when the app is removed ?

Answer (score 0):

*firebaser here*

There's no definite period on when the token will be invalidated. You don't need to add any implementation for token validation when the app is uninstalled.

There can be instances that if no new token is generated, the old token will still be valid even if the app is uninstalled. Best practice for token management is just to retrieve the latest token and use it. If you determine in some way that the app is unstalled, just remove the token from your server as part of token monitoring. Just a side note that FCM should not be used to determine if an app is installed/uninstalled.